# How to import csv files in hebrew language into contacts in vtiger CRM?

Tags: hebrew, vtiger, csv-import

I want to import a csv file which contain Hebrew language, into the contacts in V-tiger CRM. I tried to import the file, but the values in Hebrew language are shown as '?????'. In database, tables are in utf8 format.
How to resolve this problem?Anybody please help me!

Answer (score 0):

The default charset is defined in `vtigerCRM/config.inc.php` file; check if you have `UTF-8` as default:

```
// default charset default value = 'UTF-8' or 'ISO-8859-1'
$default_charset = 'UTF-8';
```

(restart the Apache Server to apply the changes).